# Haskell How to sum the values in one column of a list of tuple, '"grouping by" 2 elements ?

Tags: haskell, sum, tuples

Let's say I  have a list of tuples like the following `[(LName, FName, Credits)]` where :

```
type LName = String
type FName = String
type Credits = Int
```

How can I sum all the credits of a person grouping by both the `LName` and the `FName` ? I have found a function that would do it for a list of tuples of the format `[(String, Int)]` but I cant get it to work with the format `[(String, String, Int)]`.

Here's the function I found on this discussion [Working with list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095496/working-with-list-of-tuples]) :

```
getSumCredits :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
getSumCredits = map (foo . unzip) . groupBy (\x y -> fst x == fst y) . sort            
   where foo (names, vals) = (head names, sum vals)
```

I think I cannot get it to work because of the function map or unzip.

Comment: Just convert `[(LName, FName, Credits)]` to `[(String, Int)]`, then use the function above....  A lambda and map will do this for you.

Comment: @jamshidh thanks I will try to do something like that ! You mean LName++FName to get one string?

Comment: You could also convert it to ((LName, Fname), Credits). That is a two element tuple where the first element is also a two-element tuple. Then you can match on the first element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your problem, but you could try the `on` function from `Data.Function`.

Your original function can be rewritten using `on` as

```
getSumCredits :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
getSumCredits = map (foo . unzip) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sort
   where foo (names, vals) = (head names, sum vals)
```

And the function (I think) you'd want can be written as

```
getSumCredits :: [(String, String, Int)] -> [(String, String, Int)]
getSumCredits = map (foo . unzip3) . groupBy ((==) `on` (\(x, y, _) -> (x, y))) . sort            
   where foo (lnames, fnames, vals) = (head lnames, head fnames, sum vals)
```